# Use openCV to photography

Tags: c++, opencv, photo

Many webcams today can take static pictures in high resolution. e.g. Logitech C920 should be able to make `16Mpx` photography, while in live video mode it can produce frames only in Full HD. Is it possible to use OpenCV to get this `16Mpx` photo? All examples I found only using `VideoCapture` or `cvCaptureFromCAM` which can only access the frames of live video.

Comment: Have you tried to change the resolution with CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT? [docu](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)

Comment: You should check ffmpeg support or not since OpenCV use ffmpeg to manage video I/O.

Comment: Where did you get the info that the C920 can take 16Mpx ? The only thing I could find is this thread on sparkbooth mentionning the sensor is actually only 3Mpx http://help.sparkbooth.com/discussions/sparkbooth-dslr-beta/4962-high-resolution-photos-with-logitech-c920#:~:text=The%20Logitech%20C920%20is%20one,picture%20should%20be%20about%204800x3200.